# Identify font on image

Tags: font-identification

What font is used on this image? I browsed adobe typekit and google fonts but didn't found it.

[image]

Comment: Hi Krab, we have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and [edit] your question to include that information. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a take on Museo font.

https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/exljbris/museo?utm_source=fontsquirrel.com&utm_medium=matcherator_link&utm_campaign=museo

Used the font identifier on Font Squirrel to match an image of the font to several closely related ones.

https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator

Hopefully this was helpful!

Comment: it looks similiar, i already found this one, but it is not exact

Comment: it looks pretty much the same except for a few end points on letters like c, z, and y. But if this isn't what you're looking for, then I wish you luck

Comment: Those c, z, and y terminals look sufficiently non-standard to assume they were changed manually.